# Console prints out undefined. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Person(name,age){
  this.name=name;
  this.age=age;
}
var person1 = new Person("name1",4)
  var person2 = new Person("name2",6)
function Animal(name,size){
  this.name=name;
  this.size=size;
}
var animal1=new Animal("name1","small")
var animal2 = new Animal("name2","big")
Person.prototype.sayName=function(){
  console.log("Hello "+[name])
}
Animal.prototype.sayName=function(){
  console.log("Hello "+[name])
}
animal1.sayName();
```

I just learned Javascript and I started playing around with some code. When I run this code, the console prints out undefined. I believe the console should print : "Hello animal1". What is wrong with it?

Comment: What do you think `[name]` does exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, when you say **new**, first thing that would happen is that an empty object would be created. Upon the creation of this object, the animal function is executed and the current execution context would be referring to newly created empty object. So when you say this.name = name and this.size = size, the **this** keyword would be referring to the newly created object. So you need to always reference the property with **this**, while accessing it as shown in the below snippet:

```js
function Animal(name,size){
  this.name=name;
  this.size=size;
}
var animal1=new Animal("name1","small")

Animal.prototype.sayName=function(){
  console.log("Hello "+this.name)
}
animal1.sayName();
```

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the `this` keyword to refer to the current instance.

```
Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
  console.log("Hello "+ this.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("Hello " + [name])` should be `console.log("Hello " + this.name)`

I tried it in my console, now it outputs `Hello name1`.